# Regex for mobile number with optional country code

Tags: java, regex

actually i am using it at internal application which generate a xml, whose code is written in java. But here at application if ^(249)?1\d{8}$ then it forward to next operation, if number not above then give user wrong input i.e. I am not directly interact to java codeI want a regex for mobile number validation. The regex pattern should be such that it must accept 249 country code(only once) followed by '1' (only once) followed by 8 digit. Country code should be optional.If country code doesn't exist, it should accept only 9 digit number which started with 1.

Also Regex which negate above condition, means any mobile number which not start with 249 and having length 12, if it of length 9 and not start with 1.
The regex should accept numbers like

```
249189372837 start with 249 followed by 1 and must of 12 digit length
249123476358 
183526352  if start with 1 and must of 9 digit length (249 optional)
```

Should not accept

```
2431983645238   country code not 249
24924356383799  more then 12 digit including country code
249212236472 not 1 after 249
1232345678   more length then 9
12345323     less length then 9
456278399    if 249 is not there then mut start with 1 with length of 9
```

So I need regex for accepting above condition and one regex which accept any number other then above accepting condition.

I tried this `^(249)([1]{1})([0-9]{8})$` when start with `249` then (1) then 8 digits and `^(1)([0-9]{8})$` when number start with 1 followed by 8 digit, but I require one regex for both condition.

actually i am using it at internal application which generate a xml, whose code is written in java. But here at application if ^(249)?1\d{8}$ (answered by @rock321987) then it forward to next operation, if number not above regex then give user wrong input i.e. I am not directly interact to java code

Lots of thanks in advance for any help and suggestion.

Comment: What have you tried? You should have a go at it first before asking for help and then come with your problems with your trials

Comment: @Darken thanks for prompt response, till now i tried it  ^(249)([1]{1})([0-9]{8})$  when start with 249 then (1) then 8 digits and ^(1)([0-9]{8})$ when number start with 1 followed by 8 digit, but i require one regex for both condition

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oC9cY6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex will work

```
^(249)?1\d{8}$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oC9cY6/1)**

For second part

```
(?=^1)(^\d{1,8}$|^\d{10,}$)|(?=^2491)(^\d{1,11}$|^\d{13,}$)
(?!^(2491|1))^(\d{9}|\d{12})$
```

*Java Code*

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
String pattern = "^(249)?1\\d{8}$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
while (true) {
    String line = x.nextLine();
    Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
         System.out.println("Found -> " + m.group());
    } else {
         System.out.println("Not Found");
    }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/4pFU3b)**

Comment: thanks a lots for your prompt answer, it work, alternetely I also create other  ^(^(249)?)?[1]{1}\d{8}$ tested at http://www.regextester.com/ but your answer is shorter, please help to one regex to negate this above condition

Comment: Please suggest a negeat of above Regex too, mean which accept anything except ^(249)?1\d{8}$

Comment: I will accept your answer, but it solve only one part, so please suggest for second part too

Comment: actually i am using it at internal application which generate a xml, whose code is written in java. But here at application if ^(249)?1\d{8}$ then it forward to next operation, if number not above then give user wrong input  i.e. I am not directly interact to java code.

Comment: thanks a lots for your valuable time given, above link nearing to my answer, except two case i.e. (1)- when number start 249 followed by 1 then followed by less or more digit then 12 (2)- if number start with 1 then followed by less or more digit then 9

Comment: @ArvindGangwar Do you want to `match them` or `not match them`?

Comment: @ArvindGangwar clarify please

Comment: @ArvindGangwar what you are saying can be achieved through :- https://regex101.com/r/oC9cY6/6

Comment: actually i want two regex for one which you answered and other for all following cases as invalid mobile number,is as (1) if number started with 249 followed by 1 followed by 8 digits but total length not equal to 12 digits i.e. 2491324567892 (here total length is greater then 12) (2) if number start with 1 but total length not equal to 9 digits i.e. 123232478  (total length not equal to 9) (3) if number not start with 249 or 1 (i.e. any other combination except 249 or 1) and any length of digits i.e. 243123432412 (not start with 249) or 312123435 (not start with 1)

Comment: @ArvindGangwar For 1) and 2) use https://regex101.com/r/oC9cY6/6

and for 3) use https://regex101.com/r/oC9cY6/7

Comment: separately it work for my requirement, but if possible one regex for both (i.e. for invalid series number), if not then i use it separate

Comment: @ rock321987, i pay lots of thanks to given such a valuable time to me

Comment: @ArvindGangwar I think it won't be possible to combine..If possible it will become more complicated

Comment: @ rock321987, then its ok, in last again  i pay lots of thanks to given such a valuable time and suggestion to me

Comment: @ArvindGangwar happy to help..if it will be possible to combine I will update in the evening